# fixed position header overlapping

Tags: html, css

Okay so I kind of have two problems. One is whenever I try to do position:fixed; on the .header it adds space to the bottom of the header and it makes the .main-content go behind the header and also adds margin to the top of the header. The other problem is whenever I did not have the fixed position there was space between the header and the main content and for some reason it the space is not there if I put a border on the main content. I've looked and looked over my code trying to find whats wrong with it and I just can't seem to find anything. 
 Thanks for any help!

```css
/***********************************
          LOGO
***********************************/
.header{
background-color: skyblue;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width: 100%;
}
.logo{
text-align: left;
display: block;
margin:0 15px 0px 15px;
}
#logo-large{
display: inline;
font-size: 3em;
font-weight: 200%;
font-family: 'Dosis' , sans-serif;
}
#logo-small{
display: inline;
font-weight:0;
font-size: 2.5em;
font-family: 'Dosis' ,sans-serif;
}
/************************************
           NAVIGATION
************************************/
nav ul{
list-style-type:none;
/****display: block;
padding: 5px;
margin: 5px;
text-align: center;****/
}
nav{
display:inline;
float: right;
}
nav ul li{
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px 0px;
margin: 0;
}
nav ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
padding:20px 12px 12px 12px;
color:black;
font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.25em;
}
nav ul li a:active, nav ul li a:hover{
background-color: deepskyblue;
color: white;
}
/*************************************
           main content
*************************************/
.main-content{
background-color: grey;
font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
margin:0;
padding:10px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>FatHead | Blog</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,500,600,700,800|Muli:400,300italic,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
     <div class="logo">
        <h1 id="logo-large">FAT</h1> <h1 id="logo-small">HEAD</h1>
        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
    <h1>Welcome to my blog!</h1>
    <p>This would be where all the content inside the blog post goes.</p>
</div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: As like this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/y5L3qqaa/

Comment: yes, just like that. what did you do to fix it, just add margin to the top of the  body?

Comment: no  body define  {padding-top: 65px;} ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Now just add to this css** define your `.header` `position :fixed` and define your `body` `padding-top:65px;`

```
 .header{
        position: fixed;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        top:0;
    }
    html body {
     padding-top: 65px;
    }
```